# Validate a string between another string?

Tags: c#, regex, string

I am developing an ASP.NET application in which I have to display description for text documents after performing SQL full text search query. I have to highlight the user input search string with in description of that document. Now problem is that:

If the user enters **rang** as input search string then I have to check whether that string is part of another word or appears as an individual word. For example:

1 - **rang** may appear by itself or it may be part of some word i.e. W**rang**ling.

2 - **weep** may appear by itself or it may be part of **weep**ing.

How can I validate such condition for strings? Is it possible through `Regex.Match()`?
Any help will be much appreciated.

**NOTE**: A single word may appear multiple times in multiple ways within a paragraph.

Comment: @DarthVader: Actually I have to perform highlighting after document search.

Comment: I gather that the problem is that you want to highlight whole words like _weep_ in a different way than _sweep_? So it's nothing toi do with the SQL query?

Comment: are you done with searching? for syntax highlighting, you can use string.Contain. then string.indexOf then you can highlight it.

Comment: @DarthVader : Is it possible to check my condition with in some paragraph by using string.Contain?A single word can appear multiple times in multiple ways in a paragraph.

Comment: if it appears multiple `rang` appears multiple times in multiple words so be it. if the user is searching for that, you are doing what you are supposed to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in regex

```
string word=Regex.Escape("rang");//your word..used regex.escape to escape regex characters if any

Regex rx = new Regex("\b(.*?)"+word+"(.*?)\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

foreach (Match m in rx.Matches(yourInputText))
{
    if(m.Groups[1]!="" || m.Groups[2]!="")
    {
        //the word is between some words
    }
    else
    {
        //the word occurs separately
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE Column LIKE "%rang%";`

in your sql query you can use %rang% which will match anything that has like.

something like above.

Comment: I have to validate it in my application.

Comment: see my comment. you can use string contains. then for highlighting string indexof.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to do that through your SQL query itself using the `LIKE` [operator](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/like.php).

```
SELECT * FROM <table name> WHERE <column name> LIKE '%rang%'
```

Comment: This is not the required answer, it will simply return the rows containing the given text, but will not enable highlighting all the occurances of the given word

Answer (score 0):

To find out if something is a word in a string, just check if it's delimited by non-word characters.
For instance, if you define a word as having only letters, do something like this

```
bool ContainsWord(string phrase, string word)
{
   int i = phrase.IndexOf(word); if (i<0) return false;
   return (i==0 || !char.IsLetter(phrase[i-1])) &&
      (i==phrase.Length-word.Length || !char.IsLetter(phrase[i+word.Length]));
}
```

Comment: too complicated. is this really necessary?

Comment: If you have a library call to make this simpler, just post it.